# Put Java application into file manager's context menu

Tags: java, linux, contextmenu, file-manager, nautilus

I'm using Eclipse IDE on Ubuntu. My app offers encryption services and I want to integrate it into the client OS. My question is:
Is there a way to put my app programmatically into the context menu (right-click options) of the file manager, irrespective of the file manager a person is using? I would also like to know if there is any way I could do this on Windows explorer as well. But my guess is that it involves adding values to the registry and can be easily achieved.

So, is there a general solution to adding context-menu support on linux file managers, and also please correct me if I'm wrong about doing it in the windows system.

Please inform me if the question is unclear.

Comment: What context menu of which specific ui element? Desktop-background? "Start"-Menu? Notification area? File-browser? (Btw, I don't think so - just look at the differences between gnome-shell, kwin and awesome-WM for example ;-))

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of an widely-known application that already implements your desired behaviour? It would help understanding what you mean...

Comment: @amon the context menu i'm referring to is the one we get when we right-click on a file inside the file browser/explorer. For eg., in ubuntu, when you right click on a file, you get option for the "Ubuntu one" app to share the file.

Comment: Ah, now I see. you are *not* referring to "window managers", but to "file managers" like *Explorer, Nautilus, Thunar, Finder, Dolphin, Konqueror, Commander etc.* This link covers adding menu items to Nautilus in C: http://taschenorakel.de/svn/repos/bulldozer/tags/release-0.1.0/documentation/NautilusExtensions.html#id2427902

Comment: @amon thank you for that link. But does this mean I've to do this specifically for every file manager?

Comment: @rahules I really think there is no easy way, but I don't know for sure. A google search like `Nautilus plugin tutorial` or `Dolphin plugin tutorial` could maybe help. However, I highly doubt there will be a Java interface; you might need some C++ glue.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_Applications#Troubleshooting hints that adding `%U` to the `Exec`=` field in the `.desktop` file should perhaps make it appear in the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target vanilla ubuntu, you can assume that the file manager is Gnome Nautilus. 
You can write an extension (probably in Vala/C/python) to nautilus :

http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/

Or you could re-use existing extensions, like nautilus-action or nautilus-script which allow you to bind scripts to contextual-menu entries.

If you want to support all file managers out there, you have to look at dolphin(for KDE), thunar(for xcfe), and maybe pcmanfm...

Edit :
If you want to write your plugin in java, you might want to look at Gobject Introspection. Don't know if it works yet.