# How to add context menus to ubuntu from my software?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, contextmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Put Java application into file manager's context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11549529/put-java-application-into-file-managers-context-menu)

I have a software that in windows I add a registry key so that in Windows Explorer, the person can right click on any image and then choose to run my application. (Resize Images)

I wonder how one would go about doing that for Ubuntu (or any Linux Distro) I have read through many how-tos and they all include using a software to add to the right click, however, I want to be able to create the right click menu from my own code.

I am writing the software in python for Linux, it works using c# in windows.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I honestly don't know where to start. I wondered if there was a registry type alternative in linux

Comment: Remember that "Linux" is not a coherent operating system. While things like that has been more or less standardized there are probably still differences depending on what desktop environment is used (if any) and what GUI framework you want to use.

Comment: it's probably different for each file-system explorer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg hence I have given as much info as I can. Ubuntu - Gnome and Python - WxPython.